# configuring Deployer in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

I am working on SDL Tridion 2011 Sp1 publishing concepts.

When I publish the page, all pages are getting stored at location **"c:\temp".**

This location was configured under**"\config\cd_storage_conf.xml".**

```
<Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultFile" defaultFilesystem="false">
                <Root Path="c:\temp" />
            </Storage>
            <Storage Type="filesystem" Class="com.tridion.storage.filesystem.FSDAOFactory" Id="defaultDataFile" defaultFilesystem="true" defaultStorage="false">
                <Root Path="c:\temp\data" />
            </Storage>
```

I am trying to configure the Deployer. I found cd_deployer_conf.xml under config folder and understood that we need to configure Deployer details here.

But I am unable to find Deployer folder in Tridion installed folder.

So, My doubt whether Deployer will be directly available under Tridion installation folder or do we need to procure it seperately.

Can any one share inputs aabout configuring the Deployer

Apologies if the Question is very basic.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to copy the files from the following folder and modify it for your own needs:

> [TridionInstallerFolder]\Content Delivery\configuration\samples

However, if you need some basic knowledge on setting up the deployer, your first stop should be:

- "[Installing the Content Delivery Server](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=Install_ContentDeliveryServer_intro.xml&docid=concept_FFBC376AF96D4EBBB0E346C18A711187&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocconcept_FFBC376AF96D4EBBB0E346C18A711187)" Manual (Login Required):

The installation also depends on what type of deployer you are setting up

- Deployer as application, running on **Tomcat**:

  http://sdltridionworld.com/articles/sdltridion2011/tutorials/deployer-and-odata-1.aspx
- Deployer as application, running on **IIS**:

  http://nunolinhares.blogspot.in/2011/07/manually-configuring-tridion-2011-net.html

Answer (score 5):

A lot of stuff available online for same. but I personally would prefer

http://nunolinhares.blogspot.in/2011/07/manually-configuring-tridion-2011-net.html